# I'm trying to get some photos on JS using img.src as my teatcher instructed but the code won't work. My code looks exactly the same tho

Tags: javascript, html

The only thing VSCODE points as an error is the .src parts and them it won't load any of the images, doesn't matter the hour, it just don't care about the image anymore, so I really don't know what might be causing this error, tried looking around for similar stuff, but couldn't find anything...Sorry peeps.

```
 function carregar(){
    var msg = window.document.getElementById('msg')
    var img = window.document.getElementById('foto')
    var data = new Date()
    var hora = data.getHours()
    msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hora} horas.`
    if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
        //BOM DIA!!!!
        img.src= 'morning.png'
    } else if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){
        //BOA TARDE!!!
        img.src = 'noon.png'
    }else{
        //BOA NOITE!!!
        img.src = 'night.png'
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hora do dia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex002.css">
</head>
<body onload="carregar()">
    <header>
        <h1>Hora do Dia</h1>
    </header>
        <section>  
            <div id="msg">
                Aqui vai aparecer a mensagem
            </div>
            <div id="foto">
                <img src="" alt="foto equivalente ao horário atual">
            </div>
        </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&COPY; CursoEmVídeo </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="ex002.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really hope I'm not missing some basic stuff like juniors do all the time. But I'm pretty sure it'll be the case

EDIT: It was a rookie mistake, My id was on my div and not on my image, so that's why it wouldn't work.

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the program is not taking the images as it should. none of them

Comment: What is the error message that it points to?? That text will tell us what is wrong.

Comment: If you could share your html code to see if you added id correctly to the image, that would help

Comment: my guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: I shared the html part too, sorry i didn't though about it sooner, and thanks for letting me know about how it would help!

Comment: You are selecting the div and not the image inside the div.  `<div id="foto">` is not an image

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the images in the same place than your code? Because if not, that's why you can not change the source. In case the images are in another folder, try relative path, you can read about relative paths here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: They're all on the same path, but thanks c: